# Numpy off-anti-diagonal fancy indexing

Tags: python, numpy, indexing

Is it possible to convert the following fancy indexing to basic indexing using NumPy slices?

```
import numpy as np
fancy_indices = np.arange(10), 18 - np.arange(10)
source = np.arange(400).reshape(20, 20)
 
target = source[fancy_indices]
```

These fancy indices are pointing to off-anti-diagonal elements of the matrix. The stride step between elements is also fixed. Is there a way to use basic indexing, as opposed to fancy indexing, to achieve the same `target` (so that the returned array does not own data and is not memory contiguous), whilst still having readable code?

Comment: fancy indexing implies indexing by arrays or slices, what's the benefit *to use basic indexing* in your case?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest using basic indexing has the advantage that the slice does not own the data. It allows programs to be scaled to extremely large datasets without exploding memory.

Comment: With basic you get a block. But stride tricks might get what you want, though it might also require reversing tbe array.

Comment: While possible, I can't think of any readable ways to do so... would your starting point be the pair of fancy indices? Or something different?

Answer (score 1):

```
In [40]: target
Out[40]: array([ 18,  37,  56,  75,  94, 113, 132, 151, 170, 189])
In [48]: res = np.diagonal(source[:,::-1],1)[:10]
In [49]: res
Out[49]: array([ 18,  37,  56,  75,  94, 113, 132, 151, 170, 189])
```

`res` is `view` of source, but it's a read-only:

```
In [54]: source[0,18]=1000
In [55]: res
Out[55]: array([1000,   37,   56,   75,   94,  113,  132,  151,  170,  189])

In [56]: res[0]=18
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError: assignment destination is read-only
```

looking at the code for `np.diag`, we see that it uses `arr.flat` indexing.  So we can get the target directly with:

```
In [59]: source.flat[18:190:19]
Out[59]: array([1000,   37,   56,   75,   94,  113,  132,  151,  170,  189])
```

This, though, is not a `view`.

`np.diagonal` documents the read-only view bit.  Also demonstrates the anti-diagonal.  `np.diag` uses `np.diagonal` if given a 2d array.  `arr.diagonal` is compiled, but `np.diag` uses the `flat` trick to create a diagonal matrix.

In the comment I mentioned using `as_strided`.  This gets 10 anti-diagonal elements, but starting with 19, rather than 18.  But for this purpose `flat` is easier to use.

```
In [80]: np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(source[:,::-1], (10,), (152,))
Out[80]: array([ 19,  38,  57,  76,  95, 114, 133, 152, 171, 190])
```

Comment: `source.flat[18:190:19]` is not a view, but `source.ravel()[18:190:19]` is (when the `source` is continuous).

Answer (score 0):

I think it is difficult, because slicing is only performed per axis. What you can do, is to use generators, which has the advantage that no memory will be allocated. For example like this:

```
gen1 = (i for i in np.arange(10))
gen2 = (i for i in 18 - np.arange(10))

target = []
for i,j in zip(gen1, gen2):
    target.append(source[i,j])
```

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by @hpaulj's Answer, I think the most memory efficient ways are

```py
np.diagonal(source[:,::-1],1)[:10]
```

or

```py
target = np.diagonal(source[:, :18-10:-1], source.shape[1] - 1 - 18)
source.flat[[18, 37]] += 100  # this will be reflected in target
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).